# Разбить на страницы вывод отзывов

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, woocommerce, pagination

Реализовал вывод всех отзывов на отдельной странице.

Вопрос: есть способ их разбить на страницы по штук 10, например?

```html
function mytheme_comment_rev_page( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
 
 if ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) {
  $tag       = 'div';
  $add_below = 'comment';
 } else {
  $tag       = 'div';
  $add_below = 'div-comment';
 }

 
 ?>

 <div class="testimonials-index-wraper-block"  id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
 <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) { ?>
  <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body"><?php
 } ?>
<div class="title title-product-rev-index">


 <h6>
    <?php echo get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ); ?>
 </h6>
</div>
 <div class="comment-author avatar">
  <?php
  if ( $args['avatar_size'] != 0 ) {
   echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] );
  }
  
  ?>
 </div>
 
 <div class="author">
     <div class="name">
     <?php if (pll_current_language() == 'ru')
     { echo('Имя'); }
     if (pll_current_language() == 'ua')
     { echo("Ім`я"); }
     if (pll_current_language() == 'en')
     { echo('Name'); }
     ?>
     </div>
     <div class="city">
     <?php
     printf(
   __( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>' ),
   get_comment_author_link()
  );
     ?>
     </div>
    </div>

 <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) { ?>
  <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation">
   <?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?>
  </em><br/>
 <?php } ?>

 
 <div class="coment-text-wraper-index coment-text-wraper">
 <?php comment_text(); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="read-more">
      <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
      <?php if (pll_current_language() == 'ru')
     { echo('Читать отзыв'); }
     if (pll_current_language() == 'ua')
     { echo("Читати відгук"); }
     if (pll_current_language() == 'en')
     { echo('Read feedback'); }
     ?> 
      <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>

 <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) { ?>
  </div>
 <?php }
 
}
```

```html
<?php
   global $postid;
$postid = get_the_ID();
    $args = array ('post_id'); 
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    wp_list_comments( array( 
   'per_page' => 0,  
   'style'             => 'div', 
   'format'            => 'html5',
   'reverse_top_level' => 'true', 
   'avatar_size' => '400', 
   'callback'          => 'mytheme_comment_index',
   
   
     ), $comments);
     
     
if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
    echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
    paginate_comments_links(
     apply_filters(
      'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args',
      array(
       'prev_text' => '&larr;',
       'next_text' => '&rarr;',
       'type'      => 'list',
      )
     )
    );
    echo '</nav>';
   endif;     
?>
```

Comment: Где выводятся комментарии? в Настройках - Чтение выставляется пагинация коментариев

Comment: отдельный щаблон стрвнцы, отзывы woo, вот код вывода на странцы

Comment: укажите каким образом вы получаете комментарии

Comment: Извините должен сразу был указать, вот код со страницы отзывов (исправил вопрос)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

у get_comments  в аргументах есть number отвечающий за количество комментариев и offset количество комментариев, которые нужно пропустить.

```
$per_page        = 10;
$current_page = 1;
$args = [
    'number' => $per_page,
    'offset'    => $current_page * $per_page,
 ];
 $comments = get_comments( $args );
```

Для вывода пагинации используй:

```
get_paginate_links( [
    'total'   => 1, // Всего страниц
    'current' => 0, // Текущая страница
] );
```

Comment: не помогло, вывело только 2 штуки.

Comment: ага я тормоз, 2 вывело потому что в настройках указно 2 было, а как пагинацию отобразить подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: paginate_links с нужными параметрами

Comment: ето в функции или же на странице вставлять лучше?

Comment: На странице в том месте, где вам надо

Comment: Добавьте параметры в эту функцию 
'total'        => 1, // Всего страниц комментариев
'current'      => 0, // Текущая страница комментариев

Comment: тоесть вот так?

Comment: <?php 
$args = [
    'total'   => 1,
    'current'    => 0,
 ];
echo paginate_links( $args ) 
?>

Comment: да, только не забудьте в тотале указать ваше кол-во страниц и в каррент - текущую страницу

Comment: Рад был помочь.